# JAX-RS: How to use one resource method parameter for @BeanParam and as entity param at the same time?

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I have the following REST resource in my service class:

```
@POST
@Path("/{personId}/email")
public Response changeEmail(
    @BeanParam ChangeEmailCmd command
) {
    return runCommand(command);
}
```

I like to have the request body to be deserialized into the ChangeEmailCmd instance, and at the same time have some extra parameters (like the personId path parameter of the above example) injected into the same instance.

Is this possible at all? The above example does not work. When the 'command' parameter is annotated with @BeanParam, then the extra parameters are injected as desired, but the body is not deserialized anymore.

Is there maybe a way to mark or annotate a method parameter as "the entity"?
I tried all sorts of annotations and other hacks but no luck so far.

RESTeasy 3.0.8, Jackson 2.3.2 and Weld 2.1.2

**Edit** (added ChangeEmailCmd definition):

```
public class ChangeEmailCmd {

    public String newEmail;

    @PathParam("personId")
    public UUID personId;
}
```

Comment: What is the current definition of `ChangeEmailCmd`?

Comment: `ChangeEmailCmd` currently is a simple POJO with a default constructor.

Comment: Not sure why you're unable to share the current code to help identify the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my description is enough. BTW it doesn't work, even if I delete personId field.